# Having more of the same in a many-to-many

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In my garages I can have more of the same car, how should that be created?

What I have now is

```
class Garage {

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Car", inversedBy="garages")
     */
    private $cars;

}

class Car {

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Garage", mappedBy="cars")
     */
    private $garages;

}
```

This will not allow me to have more than 1 of the same car in my garage, but I want it to have more than 1 of the same.

In my database Doctrine create this primary key `PRIMARY garage_id, car_id` I think it is this key that is the problem.

Do I really need to create a "joiner class" to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform an association of this kind, with a third element member of the PK (as for example a PK composed by garage_id, car_id and car_plate_number), then yes you will need an association entity here.

You can see more [here in the official tutorials](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html).

Comment: I only have the name on the car, could be Audi fx - so now I want two audis in my garage - I dont need another field in the joiner table.

in my joiner table the data would be something like: garage:1 - car:1, garage:1 - car:1

Answer (score 0):

The same car for you <==> the same id ??

so you have to create a "joiner class" with a PK just a simple id and not garage_id, car_id.